# AMD support for ffmpeg? Can't get my dedicated GPU to work

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264

I'd like to ask for your advice. Recently I got refurbished Dell Latitude E6540 with two GPUs: integrated Intel HD Graphics 4600 and external AMD Radeon HD 8790M:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Mars XTX [Radeon HD 8790M]
```

Basically, what I'd like to achive is use AMD power to ffmpeg (I use it mainly to convert images sequences to movies - thousands of images in 2K-4K resolution), possibly also Digikam, GIMP, Avidemux and similar software.

I use Kubuntu 18.04.2 LTS as my distro of choice with Oibaf's graphic drivers PPA. I know how to turn on AMD on it - just use `DRI_PRIME=1` prefix with app name. So if I run `DRI_PRIME=1 glxinfo` I get (only OpenGL excerpt):

```
OpenGL vendor string: X.Org
OpenGL renderer string: AMD OLAND (DRM 2.50.0, 4.18.0-17-generic, LLVM 8.0.0)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 19.1.0-devel (git-3c5a9ab 2019-04-17 bionic-oibaf-ppa)
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL version string: 4.5 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 19.1.0-devel (git-3c5a9ab 2019-04-17 bionic-oibaf-ppa)
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: compatibility profile
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 19.1.0-devel (git-3c5a9ab 2019-04-17 bionic-oibaf-ppa)
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
```

But if I test my notebook with `radeon-profile` app (https://github.com/marazmista/radeon-profile), I get:

```
VGA: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
VGA: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Mars XTX [Radeon HD 8790M]
OpenGL driver: not direct rendering capable.
Kernel driver: radeon
name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
    Vendor: Intel Open Source Technology Center (0x8086)
    Device: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Haswell Mobile  (0x416)
    Version: 19.1.0
    Accelerated: yes
    Video memory: 1536MB
    Unified memory: yes
    Preferred profile: core (0x1)
    Max core profile version: 4.5
    Max compat profile version: 3.0
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.1
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Haswell Mobile 
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 19.1.0-devel (git-3c5a9ab 2019-04-17 bionic-oibaf-ppa)
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 19.1.0-devel (git-3c5a9ab 2019-04-17 bionic-oibaf-ppa)
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.1 Mesa 19.1.0-devel (git-3c5a9ab 2019-04-17 bionic-oibaf-ppa)
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.10
```

So why it is? If I call AMD by `DRI_PRIME=1 radeon-profile` and see kernel driver `radeon`, next massages are about Intel GPU? And why one of the messages says *OpenGL driver: not direct rendering capable*?

Next test: `mpv`. My personal `mpv.conf` is:

```
gpu-context=auto
hwdec=auto
vo=gpu
profile=gpu-hq
fullscreen=yes
scale=ewa_lanczossharp
cscale=ewa_lanczossharp
```

I call mpv with: `DRI_PRIME=1 mpv --msg-level=vo/opengl=debug --log-file=mpv-debug.log big_buck_bunny_1080p_stereo.avi` and I see that AMD is used:

```
[   0.049][v][vo/gpu] Probing for best GPU context.
[   0.049][v][vo/gpu/opengl] Initializing GPU context 'x11probe'
[   0.049][v][vo/gpu/x11] X11 opening display: :0
[   0.051][v][vo/gpu/x11] X11 running at 1920x1080 (":0" => local display)
[   0.052][v][vo/gpu/x11] Detected wm supports NetWM.
[   0.052][v][vo/gpu/x11] Detected wm supports FULLSCREEN state.
[   0.052][v][vo/gpu/x11] Detected wm supports ABOVE state.
[   0.052][v][vo/gpu/x11] Detected wm supports BELOW state.
[   0.052][v][vo/gpu/x11] Detected wm supports STAYS_ON_TOP state.
[   0.052][v][vo/gpu/x11] Display 0 (eDP-1): [0, 0, 1920, 1080] @ 60.005696 FPS
[   0.052][v][vo/gpu/x11] Current display FPS: 60.005696
[   0.120][v][vo/gpu/opengl] GLX chose FB config with ID 0xe7
[   0.120][v][vo/gpu/opengl] GLX chose visual with ID 0x13e
[   0.123][v][vo/gpu/opengl] Creating OpenGL 4.4 context...
[   0.130][v][vo/gpu] GL_VERSION='4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 19.1.0-devel (git-3c5a9ab 2019-04-17 bionic-oibaf-ppa)'
[   0.130][v][vo/gpu] Detected desktop OpenGL 4.5.
[   0.130][v][vo/gpu] GL_VENDOR='X.Org'
[   0.130][v][vo/gpu] GL_RENDERER='AMD OLAND (DRM 2.50.0, 4.18.0-17-generic, LLVM 8.0.0)'
[   0.130][v][vo/gpu] GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION='4.50'
```

When I call it without DRI_PRIME=1, relevant message says:

```
[   0.074][v][vo/gpu] GL_VERSION='4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 19.1.0-devel (git-3c5a9ab 2019-04-17 bionic-oibaf-ppa)'
[   0.074][v][vo/gpu] Detected desktop OpenGL 4.5.
[   0.074][v][vo/gpu] GL_VENDOR='Intel Open Source Technology Center'
[   0.074][v][vo/gpu] GL_RENDERER='Mesa DRI Intel(R) Haswell Mobile '
[   0.074][v][vo/gpu] GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION='4.50'
```

I also installed `radeontop` and `intel-gpu-tools` to monitor utilization of both GPUs and if I run mpv with DRI_PRIME=1, `radeontop` is working (values different than 0%), if without - `intel_gpu_top` is showing meaningful values and radeontop is empty.

Now come to the ffmpeg. I googled many sites and tried many commands to force ffmpeg to work as expected. As far, no luck, so I'm asking here. But what I found until now?

I've downloaded several clips from here: https://standaloneinstaller.com/blog/big-list-of-sample-videos-for-testers-124.html for testing, especially MP4 1920x1080 Panasonic_HDC_TM_700_P_50i movie. I reviewed instructions from the first hand: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Hardware/VAAPI

First I tried to capture the screen: `ffmpeg -vaapi_device /dev/dri/renderD128 -f x11grab -video_size 1920x1080 -i :0 -vf 'hwupload,scale_vaapi=format=nv12' -c:v h264_vaapi -qp 24 output.mp4` but ended with *[h264_vaapi @ 0x558a43ee63c0] No usable encoding entrypoint found for profile VAProfileH264High (7).
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
Conversion failed!*

Then the same with different combinations of `DRI_PRIME=1 LIBVA_DRIVER_NAME=radeonsi` prefix - same result, same error message. So I googled for *No usable encoding entrypoint found for profile VAProfileH264High message* but didn't found nothing which clarify it, only more confusion. So I tried different approach - `vainfo`.

Clear `vainfo` gives:

```
libva info: VA-API version 1.1.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_1
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
vainfo: VA-API version: 1.1 (libva 2.1.0)
vainfo: Driver version: Intel i965 driver for Intel(R) Haswell Mobile - 2.1.0
vainfo: Supported profile and entrypoints
      VAProfileMPEG2Simple            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileMPEG2Simple            : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileMPEG2Main              : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileMPEG2Main              : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264MultiviewHigh      : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264MultiviewHigh      : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264StereoHigh         : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264StereoHigh         : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileVC1Simple              : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVC1Main                : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVC1Advanced            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileNone                   : VAEntrypointVideoProc
      VAProfileJPEGBaseline           : VAEntrypointVLD
```

`vainfo` with `DRI_PRIME=1` gives:

```
libva info: VA-API version 1.1.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: User requested driver 'radeonsi'
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/radeonsi_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_1
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
vainfo: VA-API version: 1.1 (libva 2.1.0)
vainfo: Driver version: Mesa Gallium driver 19.1.0-devel for AMD OLAND (DRM 2.50.0, 4.18.0-17-generic, LLVM 8.0.0)
vainfo: Supported profile and entrypoints
      VAProfileMPEG2Simple            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileMPEG2Main              : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVC1Simple              : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVC1Main                : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVC1Advanced            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileNone                   : VAEntrypointVideoProc
```

On ArchWiki I found something interesting (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Hardware_video_acceleration#Verification): *VAEntrypointVLD means that your card is capable to decode this format, VAEntrypointEncSlice means that you can encode to this format.* So does it mean AMD is unable to convert (encode) to H264?

Next test - `vdpauinfo`. For Intel it gives error and doesn't run as expected but with `DRI_PRIME=1 vdpauinfo`:

```
display: :0   screen: 0
API version: 1
Information string: G3DVL VDPAU Driver Shared Library version 1.0

Video surface:

name   width height types
-------------------------------------------
420    16384 16384  NV12 YV12 
422    16384 16384  UYVY YUYV 
444    16384 16384  Y8U8V8A8 V8U8Y8A8 

Decoder capabilities:

name                        level macbs width height
----------------------------------------------------
MPEG1                          --- not supported ---
MPEG2_SIMPLE                    3  9216  2048  1152
MPEG2_MAIN                      3  9216  2048  1152
H264_BASELINE                  41  9216  2048  1152
H264_MAIN                      41  9216  2048  1152
H264_HIGH                      41  9216  2048  1152
VC1_SIMPLE                      1  9216  2048  1152
VC1_MAIN                        2  9216  2048  1152
VC1_ADVANCED                    4  9216  2048  1152
MPEG4_PART2_SP                  3  9216  2048  1152
MPEG4_PART2_ASP                 5  9216  2048  1152
DIVX4_QMOBILE                  --- not supported ---
DIVX4_MOBILE                   --- not supported ---
DIVX4_HOME_THEATER             --- not supported ---
DIVX4_HD_1080P                 --- not supported ---
DIVX5_QMOBILE                  --- not supported ---
DIVX5_MOBILE                   --- not supported ---
DIVX5_HOME_THEATER             --- not supported ---
DIVX5_HD_1080P                 --- not supported ---
H264_CONSTRAINED_BASELINE       0  9216  2048  1152
H264_EXTENDED                  --- not supported ---
H264_PROGRESSIVE_HIGH          --- not supported ---
H264_CONSTRAINED_HIGH          --- not supported ---
H264_HIGH_444_PREDICTIVE       --- not supported ---
HEVC_MAIN                      --- not supported ---
HEVC_MAIN_10                   --- not supported ---
HEVC_MAIN_STILL                --- not supported ---
HEVC_MAIN_12                   --- not supported ---
HEVC_MAIN_444                  --- not supported ---
```

So most of H264 profiles aren't supported? I tried to add `-profile:v baseline` switch to `ffmpeg` command but ended with:

```
[h264_vaapi @ 0x55929d9c8300] [Eval @ 0x7ffdb7f59060] Undefined constant or missing '(' in 'baseline'
[h264_vaapi @ 0x55929d9c8300] Unable to parse option value "baseline"
[h264_vaapi @ 0x55929d9c8300] Error setting option profile to value baseline.
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
Conversion failed!
```

And I digged again, founding this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ffmpeg/+bug/1805712/comments/2

And my hopes died here. If I understand it properly, I can't use AMD GPU to encode because this chip doesn't have this capability built-in. So how can I use the power of this GPU in Linux? Currently I use open-source drivers (radeon/radeonsi) and I've read that open-source driver for AMD is good so I didn't have reason for change. I tried to avoid external solution, but maybe the time has come...? Does it change anything?

EDIT: I reply to my own last question. No, it doesn't change anything, so I came back to system drivers (from Oibaf's repo).

Comment: Since you're generating a movie from images or screen cap, **de**coding capabilities are irrelevant. **En**coding is the relevant operation, And it appears your device does not support video encoding.

Comment: Thank you for reply. My awkward trials are probably caused by lack of knowledge how whole encoding stack works (communication between CPU and GPU, implemented features from codecs etc.).